# ROW_NUMBER() as transient attribute in entity based view object

Tags: sql, oracle-adf, oracle11gr2

Is it possible to have an transient attribute, in an entity based view object that would result in query, with the following in its select list:

```
   ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
      PARTITION BY A, B
      ORDER BY C
   ) AS AttrName
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

not sure if understand the question correctly, but as far as I understand - you need Oracle analytic functions inside some particular VIEW definition. Is that correct?
this works fine (emp is the standard table which is delivered with different oracle schema. In my case I used Apex schema, as far as I remember it exists in SCOTT schema also) :

```
create or replace view emp_serialized as
SELECT empno, deptno, hiredate,
ROW_NUMBER( ) OVER (PARTITION BY
deptno ORDER BY hiredate
NULLS LAST) SRLNO
FROM emp
WHERE deptno IN (10, 20)
ORDER BY deptno, SRLNO;

select * from EMP_SERIALIZED;
```

Here is the output:

```
view EMP_SERIALIZED created.
     EMPNO     DEPTNO HIREDATE       SRLNO
---------- ---------- --------- ----------
      7782         10 09-JUN-81          1 
      7839         10 17-NOV-81          2 
      7934         10 23-JAN-82          3 
      7369         20 17-DEC-80          1 
      7566         20 02-APR-81          2 
      7902         20 03-DEC-81          3 
      7788         20 09-DEC-82          4 
      7876         20 12-JAN-83          5 

 8 rows selected
```

If I didn't understand your question correctly - please rephrase it or try to explain in details..

Comment: I need it as attribute in an Entity-Based View Object, not as database view.

Comment: Did you try to select "Expert Mode" in "Create View Object" wizard and type analytic function there in addition to autogenerated fields?
I suppose changing "SQL Mode" to expert from normal should give you that ability

Comment: Could not try this, yet. Jdev constantly crashes, when I try. :-(

Comment: So you faced a bug and need either search oracle support site for a patch or contact someone from oracle support and ask for a patch.
I faced similar issues with different Oracle products and every time it was necessary to install some patch set over the initial installation.